# Running exe from server

Tags: php, server, localhost, exec

I can run **exe** files of my desktop from my localhost server using **exec()** function of php. But when i run the **exe** files of my desktop from my server as a client, i cannot run that. Would you please tell me how to solve the issue?

Comment: whats the exact code you try?

Comment: e.g. i have a A.exe file in my desktop and i  want to run A.exe using php from my server as a client.

Comment: What system is your server?

Comment: I am using Windows

Comment: Sorry, i am using windows OS but my server is Linux server

Comment: PHP runs on the server, it can't run programs on the client machine.

Comment: Then is it possible if i store my exe on server and run that from client machine, If yes, would you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: if your nix server will run the exe then yes. if its windows only -- then no

Comment: yes, i am using Linux server. would you please tell me how to do that?